# how to pause activity on home button in android like iPhone isBackground flag does

Tags: android

I am working on a game and i am facing a problem where i need to save my application state.

I looked for onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreState() but saving lots of calculations, makes impossible for me.

So can anybody tell me solution for saving game state, like whole activity can be saved on home button click and when i resume it open ups from where it was paused.

It is **possible in iPhone** that u can **save whole screen or put it in background** and resume it from where it was paused, managed by system or OS.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure anytime your activity goes on pause it has a chance to go to garbage collection.  I think you need to look up on how to save / store/ load states.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try saving your calculations in a file or sharedpreferences for that matter and onresume load it back up from there

Answer (score 0):

I think sharedpreferences will be useful for you......

Comment: Thnks for ur response, i have edited my question, actually i wanted to know whether it is possible to leave screen state on operating system by telling it and on resume system hand over's control to us, which is possible in iPhone.